# Handling Webdriver chrome not reachable exception

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, jenkins

When I run my automated tests on jenkins, sometimes some tests are being skipped. I'm getting the following error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable.

For what if've read on google this happens when there is and error initializing the webdriver instance. And this makes the tests skip and leaves the chromedriver.exe process still running.

Is there a way to handle the exception so when this happens I can kill the process?. Or a way on how to fix the issue so that test aren't skipped. Below is the code on how I initialize chromedriver.

```
 private void chromeDriverSetUp(){
    System.setProperty(DRIVER_PATH_PROPERTY_NAME, DRIVER_PATH);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--lang=es");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);   
    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
}
```

And this is the method that fails when the exception is thrown:

```
@Parameters({"subModel", "moduleName", "testName", "testLinkName"})
@BeforeMethod
public void handleTestMethodName(Method method, String subModel, String moduleName, String testName, String testLinkName) throws Exception
{
    this.subModel=subModel;
    this.moduleName = moduleName;
    this.testName = testName;
    this.testLinkName = testLinkName;
    this.testMethod = method.getName();
    this.testClass = method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
    initializeSelenium();
    String modulo = "";
    if(subModel.equalsIgnoreCase("ISSUER")){
        modulo = PropertiesManager.getInstance().getProperty(EPropertiesNames.MOD_ISSUER);
    }else{
        modulo = PropertiesManager.getInstance().getProperty(EPropertiesNames.MOD_ACQUIRER);
    }
    setCMSModulo(modulo);
    startAccess();
}
```